# HTML5 print screen automaticamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, captura-de-tela

É possível ou existe alguma biblioteca html5/javascript/jquery que permita que eu tire um print da janela ou de uma div e salvar automaticamente sem precisar da permissão do usuário?

Já tentei `window.print()` mas ele pede a permissão do usuário

**Obs:** eu quero salvar como imagem não enviar para a impressora

Comment: Não existe maneira perfeita de fazer isso. Tente com isto: http://experiments.hertzen.com/jsfeedback/

Comment: Uma solução para isso (mas que funciona apenas no Chrome/Opera) é a API [`chrome.desktopCapture`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture)

Comment: @Kazzkiq legal, uma outra solução, seria bem interessante se você postasse ela como resposta e com alguém exemplo feito no [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Existe um projeto *open source* chamado [`html2canvas`](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) que converte a *view* de um objeto DOM para dentro de um canvas e com isso você pode recuperá-lo na forma de imagem.

Aconselho [ler a documentação](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html) para melhores esclarecimento, o projeto é muito bom, vale a pena ver. Acho que o primordial do que você quer fazer está nessa biblioteca.