# Tirar print Screen e salvar imagem automaticamente em C#

Tags: c#

É possível tirar um print screen da página ativa de meu sistema web e salvar essa imagem em algum lugar utilizando c#?

Comment: Você quer executar o *screenshot* do sistema web simulando a execução do sistema no servidor ou ele rodando no cliente mesmo via browser?

Comment: A execução seria por parte do cliente. Ex: O usuário encontrou um erro no sistema e apenas apertando um botão em meu sistema seria enviado para o servidor a imagem da janela ativa do navegador.

Comment: Então efetivamente você gostaria que o JavaScript executasse o SS, certo? Se for isso, creio não ser possível, mas entendo pouco de  JS atual.

Comment: Acabei de ver isto http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7229/html5-print-screen-automaticamente

Comment: Sim, é possível. Próximo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É possível, com [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases), com algumas configurações.

Exemplo:

1) **WebForms**:

Na sua página WebForms coloque as referências do [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases) e [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) com seguinte código Javascript:

```cs
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
CopyBitmap = function () {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
            $.post('Handler1.ashx', { 'data': dataUrl }, function (data) {
                if (data == "1") {
                    alert('Imagem enviada com sucesso');
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

Chame o `CopyBitmap` em um botão dessa forma:

```cs
<button type="button" onclick="CopyBitmap();">Copiar</button>
```

Essa função vai pegar do canvas um base64 da imagem que vamos transferir em  processo Ajax para um arquivo `Handler1.ashx` sendo responsável pelas conversões dessa base64 para imagem e gravando no diretório `Fotos` da aplicação:

```cs
public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        String data = context.Request["data"].ToString();            
        String baseImg = Regex.Match(data, @"data:image/(?<type>.+?),(?<data>.+)").Groups["data"].Value;
        Byte[] baseBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(baseImg);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/Fotos/1-1.png") , baseBytes);            
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("1");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

2) **Web MVC**:

Em Web MVC C# é bem mais prático no método `Imagem` criado no Controler `Home` faz o recebimento e as conversões necessárias gravando a imagem em um pasta no servidor (no caso na pasta `Fotos`).

*View*

```cs
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Index - MVC</h2>
<h4>WEB MVC C#</h4>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        CopyBitmap = function () {
            html2canvas(document.body, {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
                    $.post('/Home/Imagem', { 'data': dataUrl }, function (data) {
                        if (data == "1") {
                            alert('Imagem enviada com sucesso');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        };
  </script>
<button type="button" onclick="CopyBitmap();">Copiar</button>
```

*Action:*

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Imagem(String data)
{           
    String baseImg = Regex.Match(data, @"data:image/(?<type>.+?),(?<data>.+)").Groups["data"].Value;
    Byte[] baseBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(baseImg);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Fotos/1-2-3.png"), baseBytes);
    return Json("1");
}
```

Comment: 50 pontos para Grifinória Muito obrigado Harry!

Comment: Essa foi boa ri muito @FlávioSantana, vlw.

Comment: Como faço pra salvar na área de trabalho do usuário