# Como acessar a imagem do clipboard pelo browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, área-de-transferência

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como acessar a imagem que fica no clipboard quando damos um Print Screen em alguma tela? O que eu preciso é ter acesso a imagem dando um `ctrl + v` no browser, exatamente como essa aplicação funciona:
http://pasteboard.co/

o Código que consegui para o evento é este, e funciona, contudo como acessar a imagem deste ponto?

```
$(document).bind('paste', function (evt) {
   alert('ctrl + V funciona');
});
```

Detalhe: browser : Google Chrome

Comment: Bom, eu fiz um exemplo esses dias com html2canvas e está nesse link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17450/tirar-print-screen-e-salvar-imagem-automaticamente-em-c/17480#17480. Será que ajuda?

Comment: opa, vou tentar implementar.

Comment: Entao Harry Potter, implementei contudo nao funcionou como eu esperava, digamos que eu tire um print aqui, no stack overflow, e depois eu vá no meu site e de ctrl + v, eu queria que o print que eu tirei fosse para a action que você implementou, mas oque esta indo é a imagem da minha aplicação, tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Por questões de segurança, tenho praticamente certeza que não é possível fazer isso no JavaScript puro. JQuery provavelmente não vai muito além, pois também é só uma biblioteca escrita em JS puro.

MAS... Isso não quer dizer que não dê pra improvisar uma gambiarra com o famigerado... FLASH. Dá uma olhada no ZeroClipboard, ele utiliza um binário SWF para acessar a Clipboard, mas, no caso dele, ele JOGA coisas para a área de transferência, e não PUXA.

De qualquer forma, deve ter como fazer o processo inverso; se existe alguma chance de fazer isso que você quer funcionar, é com SWF.

Comment: Vc chegou a dar uma olhada no [GitHub do próprio PasteBoard](https://github.com/JoelBesada/pasteboard)?

Comment: Aliás, o blog do autor do projeto tem informações bacanas: http://joelb.me/blog/2011/code-snippet-accessing-clipboard-images-with-javascript/

Comment: nao olhei Luiz,não sabia que tinha, vou analizar, vlw.

Comment: @Ukyron, vou tentar verificar a existência por esse plugin se tiver solução eu posto!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei este plugin 
http://www.codersgrid.com/2014/02/26/paste-js-retrieve-the-data-from-clipboard-in-javascript/

funcionou perfeitamente para meu propósito, para cópia de textos e imagens.

basta incluir o arquivo .js e utilizar o código abaixo.

```
paste = $.paste().appendTo('body');
paste.on('pasteImage', function (ev, data){
console.log("dataURL: " + data.dataURL)
});
paste.on('pasteText', function (ev, data){
console.log("text: " + data.text)
});
paste.focus(); // it's actually a hidden div element

// ... when you don't need it anymore
paste.remove();
```

exemplos e mais informações no link.